# How do I learn Python as someone who knows MATLAB and C?

Tags: python, matlab

I am a graduate student starting to do research in Mathematical Optimization. I have a code for my algorithm in MATLAB (using object-oriented programming) that I want to translate into Python because I feel it'll be a much better language to work with for large-scale data. I am fairly comfortable with MATLAB and C.

My questions are:

1) what would be a good resource to start learning? I want to be able to translate my current code into Python, and the only 'specialized' function I'm using is norm().

2) Is there a recommended editor? I am on Linux Mint.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use Eclipse if you are coming from a scientific background using Matlab, consider using Anaconda, you will need to decide between 2.7 & 3.5 versions.

Both are very, very good. And as far as a great source for learning about programming in Python. Try the Coursera courses online through University of Michigan taught by Charles Severence.

It walks you through a myriad of techniques to manipulate data and build thoughtful python code. the best part is the audit (which is free) allows you to fully participate in the course, including coding samples.

Honestly, I learned simply taking the Code Academy Python Course and by printing out a few cheat sheets then just doing it.